# Linking JS stdlib to generated kdoc

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-dokka, dokka

Developing a Kotlin/JS project, we are generating KDoc using Dokka Maven plugin. However standard JS library classes are presented as ERROR CLASS in the generated doc.

Example: having function like this:

```
fun HTMLElement.component(label: String, init: () -> Unit)
```

gives documentation:

```
fun <ERROR CLASS>.component(label: String, init: () -> Unit)
```

We are behind proxy and the Dokka plugin is configured to work offline (`<offlineMode>true</offlineMode>`). How can we link the stdlib documentation to the generated one?

**EDIT:** Seems it is related to Dokka Maven plugin, with Gradle the documentation is generated all right.

Comment: Can you attach your Dokka configuration? DId you add <platform>js</platform> to your  <configuration>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my answer elsewhere so I'll just put it here to close it.

Two things are needed: to add `<platform>js</platform>` to the plugin configuration, and to run KDoc generation after the package phase (pre-integration-test phase is recommended).

Sample configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
    <artifactId>dokka-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>dokka</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <offlineMode>true</offlineMode>
        <platform>js</platform>
        <apiVersion>...</apiVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```